# Update Variable in Stateful EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, variable-assignment, ejb-3.1

I have an EJB that gets injected into one of my classes.  The EJB has a method to start monitoring a resource from the class into which it was injected.  The monitor method has a while loop in it that needs to be broken if one of its variables is updated.  The code looks something like this:

```
public class MyObject()
{
    @EJB
    private MyEJB myEjb;

    private Collection stuffToMonitor;

    public MyObject()
    {
        //empty
    }

    public void doSomething()
    {
        // create collection of stuffToMonitor

        myEjb.startMonitoring(stuffToMonitor);

        // code that does something

        if(conditionsAreMet)
        {
            myEjb.stopMonitoring();
        }

        // more code
    }
}

@Stateful
public class MyEJB()
{
    private volatile boolean monitoringStopped = false;

    public MyEJB()
    {
        //empty
    }

    public void startMonitoring(Collection stuffToMonitor)
    {
        int completed = 0;
        int total = stuffToMonitor.size();

        while(completed < total)
        {
            // using Futures, track completed stuff in collection

            // log the value of this.monitoringStopped     
            if (this.monitoringStopped)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public voide stopMonitoring()
    {
        this.monitoringStopped = true;
        // log the value of this.monitoringStopped
    }
}
```

In my logs, I can see that the value of this.monitoringStopped is `true` after the stopMonitoring method is called, but it always logs as `false` in the while loop.

Originally, MyEJB was stateless and it's been changed to stateful and I also made the variable volatile, but the change is not picked up in the while loop.

What am I missing to get my code to get the updated value of the monitoringStopped variable?

Answer (score 0):

I think what I was trying to do is just not possible with EJBS, although if somebody knows better I would appreciate hearing from them.

Instead, I found a different way.  I added a third class, MyStatus which holds a status variable that MyObject will set instead of calling `myEjb.stopMonitoring();`.  I set MyEJB back to being a stateless bean and in the startMonitoring method pass it the MyStatus object.  It checks the status during each iteration of its while loop and will break out based on it.

Updated code:

```
public class MyObject()
{
    @EJB
    private MyEJB myEjb;

    @EJB
    private MyStatus myStatus;

    private Collection stuffToMonitor;

    public MyObject()
    {
        //empty
    }

    public void doSomething()
    {
        // create collection of stuffToMonitor

        myEjb.startMonitoring(stuffToMonitor);

        // code that does something

        if(conditionsAreMet)
        {
            myStatus.stopMonitor();
        }

        // more code
    }
}

@Stateless
public class MyEJB()
{
    private volatile boolean monitoringStopped = false;

    public MyEJB()
    {
        //empty
    }

    public void startMonitoring(Collection stuffToMonitor, MyStatus myStatus)
    {
        int completed = 0;
        int total = stuffToMonitor.size();

        while((completed < total) && myStatus.shouldMonitor())
        {
            // using Futures, track completed stuff in collection
        }
    }
}

@Stateless
public class MyStatus
{
    private boolean shouldMonitor = true;

    public void stopMonitor()
    {
        this.shouldMonitor = false;
    }

    public boolean shouldMonitor()
    {
        return this.shouldMonitor;
    }
}
```